# How to trigger suspend, resume, and background events in Metro style apps

Tags: microsoft-metro

This may seem stupid, but I can't see "the events list on the Debug toolbar" as described in this article : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974425%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Could anyone give me a more detailed description as to where I can find it? I have Visual Studio Ultimate Beta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right click any where on the menu area and select debug location and u will have it.